# Quick and clean way to find when the values of two vectors are equal, possibly for different indices

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector

Suppose I two vectors A and B, both are large, but not of the exact same size.  I can of course make them the same size by adding NaN or zeros to either A or B.

I know a priori that A and B have many entries that are the same, but I do not at which indices, and the indices may be different.  For instance I may have

```
   A(1043) = B(1048)
```

And I would like to find all such instances.  Is there a quick and clean way to do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use intersect

```
a = [5 7 10 17 35 80];
b = [6 7 15 80 27 35 77 95];
[c, ia, ib] = intersect(a, b);
```

c are the values that are in both, ia and ib are the indexes locating them such that a(ia)==b(ib).

Answer (score 0):

Can try this:

```
>> A=[123:17625];
>> B=[263:265 1:29];
>> find(ismember(A,B))

ans =

   141   142   143 %indices of A

>> find(ismember(B,A))

ans =

     1     2     3 %indices of B
```